# How to implement the bulk load to amazon Redshift from s3 bucket using Pentaho

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have downloaded the **Pentaho 9.2** community edition to implement the **bulk load to amazon Redshift** from AWS S3 bucket. But I am not able to find a way to do this using the Pentaho.

So can anyone please help me to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use pentaho for this? you just need to issue a sql command, pentaho will make things harder, not easier.

Comment: Instead of using Pentaho Data Integration, I would recommend using apache-hop (https://hop.apache.org/) Pentaho was acquired some years ago by Hitachi Vantara and the support to the community edition is non existent. If you are starting with Pentaho, just begin with Hop, previous developers of PDI took the base software of version 8.2 and migrated/cleaned/updated old code, and actively working with it modernizing the UI and implementing new features, something HV isn't doing with Pentaho.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @AnaGH can you provide the help doc of hop to fulfil the bulk loading to AWS redshift action.

Comment: hi @JonScott do you have a better solution for this? please  suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use Pentaho, use "Execute SQL Script" step. Create a connection to Redshift and run a COPY command. See an example below:

[image]

```
COPY s3_sch.event_log_int_stg (LOG_ID,EVENT_TYPE_ID,USER_ID,LOG_DESC,EVENT_LOG_DATE,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,APP_SERVER,CLIENT_ADDRESS) from '${s3redshiftpath}${SHORT_FILENAME}' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=${accessKeyId};aws_secret_access_key=${secretKey}' timeformat 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS';
```